# Is there a way to keep playing sound at zombie's location?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I make it so a sound will play only once and won't repeat when a player gets 10 blocks near a zombie? But I want the sound to play AT The location of the zombie, so it will be like 3D sound. I tried stuff but they didn't work and I'm running out of ideas.

Minecraft version: 1.18.2 Java

A command I tried in a repeating command block:

```
/execute as @e[type=zombie] at @e[type=zombie] run playsound custom.sussyb master @a[distance=0..10] ~ ~ ~
```

Comment: what did you try that didn't work? what version are you using?

Comment: 1.18.2 i tried this /execute as @e[type=zombie] at @e[type=zombie] run playsound custom.sussyb master @a[distance=0..10] ~ ~ ~ in a repeating command block

Comment: add that to your question. You can use the [edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/397528/edit) button for that.

Comment: ok i added everything to the question

Comment: I suppose it's Minecraft Java, since you didn't mention it

Comment: yes it is minecraft java

Comment: So the system resets once you go 10 blocks away from that zombie right? If so, does it have to work on each zombie individually? Meaning, a zombie gets close, they play a sound. While this one is still in range, another gets in. Does the second one play a sound? It would make the system a bit more convoluted.

Comment: yes the other sound will stop

Comment: "How do I make it so a sound will play only once and won't repeat when a player gets 10 blocks near a zombie? But I want the sound to play AT The location of the zombie, so it will be like 3D sound. I tried stuff but they didn't work and I'm running out of ideas." What question are you asking? Please edit your question to make it clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
/execute at @e[type=zombie] run playsound minecraft:ambient.cave master @a[distance=..10] ~ ~ ~
```

It should work. Just replace the `minecraft:ambient.cave` with `sussyb`